# How to create a cocos2d-x's PhysicsBody that does not rotate

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm using cocos2dx to write a simple game. I wanted to use cocos2dx's physics engine but I don't need any object to rotate from it's initial direction. It turns out I can't find a way to do it. I tried to put a static physics body and attaching other bodies to it with a PhysicsJoinMotor or PhysicsJointGear with o avail. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

body->setRotationEnable(true);

Comment: Sorry for very late comment, what is body exactly? I tried this on physicsbody and I had this error: 'class cocos2d::PhysicsBody has no member named 'SetFixedRotation'

Comment: It's now setRotationEnable I believe.

Comment: could you please edit your answer so I can accept it?